# active li list element positioning

Tags: list, html-lists, html

Ok, so I have this li list with about 24 list elements. I want the webpage to be able to automatically scroll to the point where I assigned a specific li active/current on onload. How can I do this using JavaScript?

Comment: Similar [answer][1] using jquery scrolltop 
hope it helps.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element

Comment: Was more hoping for Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a Window Object Method, scrollTo(), for scrolling (read about it here: http://w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp). However, this can be inconvenient if you don't know the exact coordinates you want to jump to. One alternative worth trying is using a named link like `<a id="active"></a>` and telling JS to load the page with #active at the end of the URL. That's always an easy way to force scrolling.